open source PXE boot for Linux?
On a simple LAN if I have server A that is running RHEL-8.10 installed from rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso or similar which then has a service that allows servers B..Z on the LAN to PXE boot from?  What would that PXE server software be called that would allow that functionality and for creating bootable Linux images?  Is there such a thing that is FOSS ?
I am interested in making servers B..Z diskless that PXE boot a Linux OS from server A.

PXE booting is handled by a DHCP server. Depending on which DHCP server is in use (sudo lsof -i :dhcp will find a local DHCP server, else check logs for who assigned your IP Address at network startup. Read the man page for bind, dnsmasq or systemd-dnsmasq, or whatever.

PXE booting is a combination of a DHCP server handing out the right DHCP records, pointing to files on a TFTP server. (this is all rather well-documented, e.g. on wikipedia!)
Thus, you need a TFTP server and a DHCP server software. Your Linux distro's package manager will tell you about a lot of options you have for these if you do apt search tftp or apt search dhcp, assuming your distro uses apt (it might use dnf or zypper or pkg or… you know your distro).
As usual, if possible, stick with what your distro recommends. For example, Fedora has an installation guide, in which there is "Advanced Installation Options" -> "Setting up an installation server", that encompasses setting up a PXE environment, and explains the components you get, and the components you'd need to build if you need that; in the end, all you need is a kernel, and an initrd, which loads the root file system using a network file system.
I'm pretty sure, debian has some wiki pages that explain the debian-recommend steps, and so on.
